# How to create SQL statement to only return chainage values every 500m?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, sql

I have a list of chainage values every 100m (as a whole number) and I am trying to create an SQL statement to only return values every 500m. Any ideas?

Using ArcGIS 10.1

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please edit this into your Question so that potential answerers will quickly understand what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is a shapefile then the following SQL statement will select all values divisible by 500.

```
mod("C",500)=0
```

"C" is your chainage value field.

Comment: The mod function changes depending on the database. This is absolutely correct for shapefiles, however when using personal geodatabase use "C mod 500 = 0" format. If one format doesn't work for your data then try the other.